# Visual studio includes Eigen/Array instead of std::array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writting some program which uses Eigen library. I am also going to use std::array but when I include  ant try to declare some, I get two errors:

1)incomplete type is not allowed

2)#error directive: The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3.

my code:

```
#include"Eigen"
#include<array>
(...)
typedef std::array<float, 3> point;
point pt;  //incomplete type error
```

I think that the IDE include Eigen/Array instead of std::array. Am I right? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: In your `(...)` do you have any using statements(`using namespace ...;`)?

Comment: There is no any using statements.

Comment: I have a feeling `point` is an exposed incomplete type from one of your includes.  What happens if you change the name to something like `foobar`?  Do you get the same error or does it compile?

Comment: Still the same after change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Eventually I removed Eigen's array header file from my code and it finally worked. This header is useless anyway with version 3.

Comment: What exactly should I remove? File "Array" from "Eigen" directory?

Comment: @KarolBorkowski, yes, exactly this file should be removed

Comment: Ok. It works, but honestly I don't like this kind of solutions ;)